# Custom web filter for specific controllers

Tags: spring-boot, filter, controller

Help me please, or show other ways to resolve this problem.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/users")
public class UserController {

    @RequestMapping("/login")
    public String logIn() {
        return "";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/getUserData")
    @FilterThisRequest
    public String getUserData(@PathVariable Long userId) {
        return user;
    }
}
```

And I have `AuthFilter extends GenericFilterBean` which makes a certain logic. How can I make that the filter execute only before methods which have `@FilterThisRequest`? Or there are better practices to resolve this problem?

Comment: While this doesn't answer your question directly, are you using Spring Security? If you are, you might consider using [global method security](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-method-security) instead. Specifically, you can use the `@PreAuthorize` annotation with SpEL or even create meta-annotations for pre-defined authorization rules. There might be other logic you want that this wouldn't work for, but just something to consider.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check FilterRegistrationBean reference guide at https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-embedded-container-servlets-filters-listeners-beans.

Make FilterRegistrationBean available to Spring via a @Configuration class, the below example will ensure that authFilter runs only for /getUserData. Note that it is URL (and not method) based filtering.

```
@Autowired AuthFilter authfilter;
....
....
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean authFilterRegistration() {
    FilterRegistrationBean registration = new FilterRegistrationBean(authfilter);
    registration.addUrlPatterns("/web-app-name/getUserData/");
    return registration;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest you for the Interceptor.

```
@Configuration 
public class Config extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
RequestInterceptor requestInterceptor;

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(requestInterceptor).addPathPatterns("/getUserData","/user");
    }

}
```

Interceptor -

```
@Component
public class RequestInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {


@Override
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response, Object object) throws Exception {
}
```

You can override Interceptor's prehandle and postHandle according to your need.

Answer (score 0):

It's way easier to just have all methods behind authentication to have a url prefix eg. `admin/` or whatever.

The suggested option of defining all URL path patterns is not efficient, application can have 100s of URL patterns to filter against

Your example would be written as below

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/users")
public class UserController {

    //...
    // changed here - added '/admin'
    @RequestMapping("/admin/getUserData")
    public String getUserData(@PathVariable Long userId) {
        return user;
    }
}
```

Create a `HandlerInterceptor` - `Spring 3.1.0` OR use the `HandlerInterceptorAdapter` for lower versions read about it on the spring website.

Create a method that checks all requests with a url prefix of `admin/` or whatever you preferred.
Use the method in the `prehandle` override method.
If the URL has a `admin/` prefix, you can then run authentication code, else ignore, see below

```
@Component
public class AdminAuthInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor
{
    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception
    {
        boolean result = true;
        if (this.isAdminPath(request))
        {
            /*
            boolean validation = true; // plug here you validation service
            if(!validation)
            {
                    try
                    {
                        response.setStatus(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.value());
                        response.setContentType("application/json");
                        response.getWriter().write("{'status':false,'msg':'User Authentication Failed'}");
                    } catch (IOException e)
                    {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
             */
        }
        return result;
    }
    private boolean isAdminPath(HttpServletRequest request)
    {
        String urlPath = request.getRequestURI();
        return urlPath != null && urlPath.contains("admin/");
    }
}
```